# Caching images with Spring MVC 3.2 using java configuration

Tags: spring, caching, spring-mvc

I have tried adding an interceptor to cache images as suggested on other stackoverflow questions, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

    WebContentInterceptor wci = new WebContentInterceptor();
    wci.setCacheSeconds(50000);
    Properties cacheMappings = new Properties();
    cacheMappings.put("/avatars/**", "50000");
    wci.setCacheMappings(cacheMappings );

    registry.addInterceptor(wci);
    registry.addInterceptor(new DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor());
}
```

I traced into the WebContentInterceptor interceptor code and it appeared to be working - matching the cacheMapping and setting the cache to 50000 seconds.  Strangely though it seems to go into the WebContentInterceptor code a second time with a mapping of "/" and therefore I get response headers like so: -

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Cache-Control:no-store
Date:Wed, 20 Nov 2013 09:59:01 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 19 Nov 2013 10:07:02 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

I also tried implementing the controller in question by extending AbstractController (instead of the annotation), but this didn't work either (same headers as above)

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- Secures the application -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>springSecurityFilterChain</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!-- Java-based Spring container definition -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Location of Java @Configuration classes that configure the components that makeup this application -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.blah.config com.blah.dataservice.repositories</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
  </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>blah</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>blah</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/login</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Here is my Java Config file

```
package com.blah.config;

import ...

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.blah.controller", "com.blah.service", "com.blah.util"}, excludeFilters = { @Filter(Configuration.class) })
@Import({ RestConfig.class, TilesConfig.class, EmailConfig.class, JmsConfig.class, Neo4jRepositoryConfig.class })
@ImportResource({ "WEB-INF/blah-applicationContext.xml",
        "WEB-INF/blah-securityContext.xml" })
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource({ "classpath:blah.application.properties", "classpath:jdbc.properties" })
public class MainConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "blah.db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "blah.db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "blah.db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "blah.db.username";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_POOL_SIZE = "blah.db.initial.pool.size";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_MAX_POOL_SIZE = "blah.db.max.pool.size";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_MIN_POOL_SIZE = "blah.db.min.pool.size";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_TEST_QUERY = "blah.db.test.query";
    private static final String PROPERTY_VALIDATION_INTERVAL = "blah.db.validation.interval";
    private static final String PROPERTY_TIME_BETWEEN_EVICTION_INTERVAL = "blah.db.time.between.eviction";
    private static final String PROPERTY_MAX_WAIT = "blah.db.max.wait";
    private static final String PROPERTY_REMOVE_ABANDONED_TIMEOUT = "blah.db.remove.abandoned.timeout";
    private static final String PROPERTY_MIN_EVICTABLE_ABANDONED_TIMEOUT = "blah.db.min.evictable.idle.time";

    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws IllegalStateException, PropertyVetoException {
        PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
        p.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        p.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        p.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        p.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        p.setJmxEnabled(true);
        p.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        p.setValidationQuery(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_TEST_QUERY));
        p.setTestOnReturn(true);
        p.setValidationInterval(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_VALIDATION_INTERVAL, Integer.class));
        p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_TIME_BETWEEN_EVICTION_INTERVAL, Integer.class));
        p.setMaxActive(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_MAX_POOL_SIZE, Integer.class));
        p.setInitialSize(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_POOL_SIZE, Integer.class));
        p.setMaxWait(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_MAX_WAIT, Integer.class));
        p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_REMOVE_ABANDONED_TIMEOUT, Integer.class));
        p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_MIN_EVICTABLE_ABANDONED_TIMEOUT, Integer.class));
        p.setMinIdle(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_MIN_POOL_SIZE, Integer.class));
        p.setLogAbandoned(true);
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        p.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");

        final DataSource sdds = new DataSource();
        sdds.setPoolProperties(p);
        return sdds;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IllegalStateException,
            PropertyVetoException {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() throws IllegalStateException, PropertyVetoException {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public TextEncryptor textEncryptor() {
        return Encryptors.noOpText();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        WildcardReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource result = new WildcardReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        String[] basenames = { "classpath:lang/msg-*.properties" };
        result.setBasenames(basenames);

        result.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordUtils pwUtils() {
        PasswordUtilsHash result = new PasswordUtilsHash();
        result.setAlgorithm(environment.getProperty("password.algorithmn"));
        result.setRegex(environment.getProperty("password.regex"));
        result.setPasswordMinLength(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("password.min.length")));

        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver result = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        result.setResolveLazily(true);
        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        WebContentInterceptor wci = new WebContentInterceptor();
        wci.setCacheSeconds(5000);
        Properties cacheMappings = new Properties();
        cacheMappings.put("/avatars/**", "5000");
        wci.setCacheMappings(cacheMappings );

        registry.addInterceptor(wci);
        registry.addInterceptor(new DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisterMemberHelper registerMemberHelper() {
        return new RegisterMemberHelper();
    }

}
```

Controller code: -

```
package com.blah.controller.avatars;

import ...

@Controller
@SessionAttributes({ SessionModel.KEY })
@RequestMapping("/avatars")
public class AvatarListController {

    @Inject
    IProfilePicService profilePicService;

    @ModelAttribute
    public void formBacking(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        SessionModel instanceSessionModel = new SessionModel();
        instanceSessionModel.retrieveOrCreate(model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{type}/{entityId}/{size}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getPic(@PathVariable String type, @PathVariable long entityId, @PathVariable String size, HttpServletResponse response, WebRequest request) throws IOException,
            InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException {

        Size sizeEnum = getSizeFromSizeString(size);

         long lastModified = profilePicService.getPicLastModifiedDate(entityId, type, sizeEnum);

        if (request.checkNotModified(lastModified)) {
            return;
         }

        InputStream is;

        is = profilePicService.getProfilePicInputStream(entityId, type, sizeEnum);


        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(is, os);
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
```

...
    }

Comment: Do the images come from your application? Or are the hosted else where? Also how are you serving those images, do you have your own controller or do you use Springs resource configuration (which already provides caching settings for you).

Comment: We are serving the images through a controller in our application (they are stored elsewhere but routed through our app).  We are using a controller rather than the Spring resource config.

Comment: Can you post your full configuration (including web.xml). My guess is you are attaching the interceptor to the wrong configuration. Please post your controller code also.

Comment: Make sure you aren't duplicating things (i.e. an `<mvc:annotation-driven somewhere />`). At first glance there seems nothing strangely wrong with your setup.

Comment: Thanks for having a look - unfortunately no <mvc:annotation-driven> tags in the project, but I'll continue along that vein - definitely seems something like that!

Answer (score 0):

I had a cache problem so, I used the following. (Disabled cache on avatar images. Intercept method didn't work for me too.)

```
@Override
protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/avatar/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/avatar/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);

        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but does this work with dynamic images that are served from a Controller?